# Do we need to have SQL Server container per microservice? 3 microservices need 3 SQL Server containers?

Tags: sql-server, docker, containers, microservices

Need to know whether each microservice container needs its specific SQL Server container or only one SQL Server container for all the microservices?

Comment: How is this related to programming? Also, if all three microservice instances have their own database, they would respond to the same request with different responses. And since containers should be state- and identity-less, this is a contradiction. Furthermore, how would we scale? Would we start up another database container if we start a new microservice-container?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not programming-related.

Answer (score 2):

If the three microservices are closely related, built by the same team, and released on the same schedule it would be reasonable for them to share a repository.

Comment: Agreed, though doing so significantly raises the temptation to share schema info between them which will lead to tears later on.  We used a single SQL Server Instance at the start, but created independent schemas which did indeed help with splitting them out later when one team became more than one.